# Firebase Database weird behavior when updating + permission_denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I discovered a weird behavior when updating data to RDB with a permission denied.

Example with minimal code necessary to reproduce the "bug":

```
getBooks() {
   firebase.database().ref("books/1").on("value", data => {
      console.log("foo", data.val());
   }
}

setAuthor() {
   firebase.database().ref("books/1").update({ "author": "foo" });
}
```

Let's suppose we have a subscription on getBooks to get data on each change.

Let's now update the author using `setAuthor` method.

***What happend if we have the permission required ?***

→ All is working fine. The log "foo" will pop with the new node where author = "foo".

***What happend if we DO NOT have the permission required ?***

→ 3 logs in the following order:

- "foo" will pop with the new node where author = "foo".
- @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: update at /books/1 failed: permission_denied
- "foo" will pope with the old node (with the original author).

*Note: This weird behavior happens only on the client trying to update `author` (fortunately). The update isn't working. To confirm that I opened another browser and there is no log poping.*

Any explanation why it's acting like there is an update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, but can indeed be confusing at first.

When you perform a write operation on a client, Firebase immediately fires events on the local listeners. It does this without waiting for a response from the server, and it's part of the reason that Firebase writes seem immediately to the local user.

It then sends the write operation to the server, and waits for a response. The response can either be an acknowledgment or a rejection of the write operation. If the server rejected the write operation, the Firebase client fires events to get the client app into the correct state again.

In a chart form:

```
     client app             SDK              Server
       +                     +                  +
       |                     |                  |
       |    write("new")     |                  |
       +-------------------->|                  |
       |                     |                  |
       |  on("value", "new") |                  |
       |<--------------------+                  |
       |                     |                  |
       |                     |   write("new")   |
       |                     +----------------->|
       |                     |                  |
       |                     |      reject      |
       |                     |<-----------------+
       |                     |                  |
       |  on("value", "old") |                  |
       |<--------------------+                  |
       |                     |                  |
       +                     +                  +
```

Comment: Thank's Puf, I was suspecting something like that. Why did you (firebase team) choose this behavior ?